# Apache License 2.0 and source code recompile

Tags: apache-license

I am not a licenses expert so I got confused a bit... The [license Apache 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0); Does it allow to get source codes and modify them for new projects? I mean modify source codes (some its parts) and recompile them?

Answer (score 1):

If you have received/downloaded source code that is covered by the Apache 2.0 licence, then you are allowed to

- Create modified versions of the source code
- Distribute the original program/library, either in source code format or as a compiled program/library
- Distribute the modified program/library, either in source code format or as a compiled program/library

If you have received/downloaded a compiled program/library that is covered by the Apache 2.0 license, then you can ask to get the source code, but there is no obligation to give it to you.

Technically, you have the same rights, whether or not you received the source code, but creating modifications without access to the source is so much harder that it probably isn't worth the effort.

Comment: In my case the source code is included in *-source.jar file but I thought can I modify it or maybe it is included just for better understanding of super objects extending or something?

Comment: @user592704: The Apache 2.0 license is a so called open source license, which means that you are always allowed to make modifications. The fact that it is in a JAR file is probably because it is a handy packaging mechanism.